# Question about char input

Tags: c++

This is what I'm trying to do...

```
char input[4];
cin >> input;
cout << "Input[0]: " << input[0] << "Input[1]: " << input[1] << "Input[2]: " << input[2] << "Input[3] " << input[3]<< "Input[4] " << input[4] <<endl;
```

However, when I enter "P F" I get an output of this: Input[0]:P Input[1]:  Input[2]:(A weird looking square with two zeros on top and a zero and 4 on the bottom)   Input[3] Input[4]

Why do I get that weird character instead of F?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin >>` separates inputs by a space, hence when you enter `P<space>F`, only the `P` is accepted into `input`, and `F` is queued for the next `cin >>`.

Thus after that `cin >> input` line, your `input` will look like

```
   input[0] = 'P';
   input[1] = '\0';
// input[2] = garbage;
// input[3] = garbage;
// input[4] = buffer-overflow;
```

Perhaps you want to use [`cin.getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/):

```
cin.getline(input, 4);
cout << ...;
```

(Or better, use `std::string` which has flexible string length.)

Answer (score 2):

Extracting from `cin` will break on a space, so it's only reading the `P`. If you want to read a line from the user you should look at `getline()`

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Comment: Any way I can have it not break on a space?

Comment: Not really, it's part of using an input stream. If you extracted from it a second time you'd get the `F`. Like I said, if you want to read whole lines you should use `getline()` instead

Comment: No, `get()` won't work -- are you reading my whole answer/comment? The documentation for `get()` even specifically says if you want to ignore delimiters you should use `getline()`. Use `getline()`. Really

Comment: But I need input to be of type char not type string.

Comment: You can do `cin.getline(input, 4)` then, as [KennyTM said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711780/question-about-char-input/2711804#2711804), assuming you meant `char*` and not `char`. You can also always get a C string from a std::string using `str.c_str()`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is actually incredibly dangerous. Your `input` variable is actually degrading into an object of type `char*`, so it is actually attempting to read a string into your `input` variable; however, since it doesn't know how many characters your `input` array can hold, it can possibly overrun `input`. Therefore, the code as you have it is actually a [buffer overflow vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Instead, you should use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
   std::cin >> input[i];
}
```

As to why you get that weird character... the stream extraction operator >> reads words that are separated by spaces, so "P F" actually only reads "P". So, your input variable gets filled with "P" (which is NUL-terminated, so you actually have 'P' then '\0'). The remaining elements are uninitialized and so have whatever garbage that happens to be there. Also, I should add that if you did want to read string, then [std::getline](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/getline) is a very good way to read std::string objects from the input as in:

```
std::string result;
std::getline(std::cin,result);
```